# How can I initialize a struct in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, initialization

I have two struct (typedef).

```cpp
typedef struct      s_bitmapheader
{
    uint16_t bfType;
    uint32_t bfSize;
    uint16_t bfReserved1;
    uint16_t bfReserved2;
    uint32_t bfOffBits;
}                   t_bitmapheader;

typedef struct      s_bitmapinfo
{
    uint32_t bisize;
    int32_t  biwidth;
    int32_t  biheight;
    uint16_t biplanes;
    uint16_t bibitcount;
    uint32_t bicompression;
    uint32_t bisizeimage;
    int32_t  biXpelspermeter;
    int32_t  biYpelspermeter;
    uint32_t biclrused;
    uint32_t biclrimportant;
}                   t_bitmapinfo;
```

In the main I have to initialize them.

First, I tried This:

```cpp
t_bitmapheader  filehdr = { 0 };
t_bitmapinfo    infohdr = { 0 };
```

And it works but I have to find another way to do this.

```cpp
t_bitmapheader  filehdr;
t_bitmapinfo    infohdr;

filehdr = { 0 };
infohdr = { 0 };
```

P.S: I Have to initialize them in another line like in the second code.

Thank You.

Comment: Hint: `bzero()` or `memset()`. For non-trivial cases where zeroing is insufficient it's common to see `init_X()` or `make_X()` type functions that initialize or allocate and initialize respectively.

Comment: `"initialization"` and `"assignment"` are different concepts. You're really looking for "assignment" as you already know how to correctly initialize to zero.

Comment: See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: Thank You all For Your help I found the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [compound literals](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compound-literals-c/) to generate anonymous structures.

```c
t_bitmapheader  filehdr;
t_bitmapinfo    infohdr;

filehdr = (t_bitmapheader){ 0 };
infohdr = (t_bitmapinfo){ 0 };
```